# UDP server process can't accept packets from kernel

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, fedora

I have a very simple UDP server program

```
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main(int argc, char**argv)
    {
       int sockfd,n;
       struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
       socklen_t len;
       char mesg[1000];

       sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
       servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
       servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
       servaddr.sin_port=htons(54000);
       bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

       for (;;)
       {
          len = sizeof(cliaddr);
          n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
          sendto(sockfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
          printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
          mesg[n] = 0;
          printf("Received the following:\n");
          printf("%s",mesg);
          printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
       }
    }
```

I put it on several machines and let a udp client to send packets to it
it can accept incoming udp packets successfully

then I place it in a machine with fedora 18 
I compile the program and run it
and then I let a udp client to send packets to it(the same as on the other machines)
but the program can't accept incoming UDP packets
I used tcpdump for capturing and I can see the incoming udp packets 
why the server program doesn't accept the incoming UDP packet on this machine?

I checked the iptables rule `iptables -L`
and the results are in

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlNHp1eTJkTFNuY0k/edit?usp=sharing

are there potential reasons for this?
thanks!

Comment: I `man iptables` and see the manual but how to check the iptables rules? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks OK at first glance.

The most obvious explanation might simply be that the Fedora 18 machine has been installed with `iptables` firewalling configured by default...

Try running `lsmod` to look for loaded `iptables` modules, and/or `iptables -L` to list the current ruleset.

Comment: I put the iptables rule in a file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlNHp1eTJkTFNuY0k/edit?usp=sharing, can you help me see which rule filters the udp packet? thanks

Comment: and lsmod https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlLWhxbjh1clZsdk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it's likely that the "default deny" policy is responsible - you'll need to add a specific "allow" policy for your application.

Comment: there are so many `deny`, if I want to open specific port for UDP/TCP, how to add? thanks!

Comment: this is now turning into a (new) question more appropriate for superuser.com